# Can I enroll my dog in the University of Texas at Arlington?

Tags: discrimination, education, animals

The University of Texas at Alrington makes [the following](https://www.uta.edu/eos-title-ix/equal-opportunity-services#:%7E:text=In%20accordance%20with%20federal%20and,%2C%20and%2For%20veteran%20status.) equal-oppertunity statement:

> In accordance with federal and state law, the University prohibits unlawful discrimination, including harassment, on the basis of race, color, national origin, religion, age, sex, sexual orientation, pregnancy, disability, genetic information, and/or veteran status.

Could I use the "genetic information" clause to enroll my dog in UTA? He is quite smart, and I want to train Bart for a career in therapy like [this dog](https://youtu.be/jq9zGC90yD0). While I don't think he would necesarily benefit from an acedemic program, the University of Texas at Arlington provides many workshops, events, and services, which are only available to students, that would help Bart expand his social skill repertoire.

Furthermore, since Bart belongs to an extremely underrepresented demographic group, would the Univeristy be required to admit him?

Comment: If Bart is an expert game retriever, sled puller, or rescue dog the uni might relax its admission requirements, as they may do for royalty, footballers, etc who they see as desirable 'students'. I don't think there is any requirement to meet a demographic quota though. Students are generally admitted on *merit*.

Answer (score 4):

Anti-discrimination laws only apply to people, see [here](https://www2.ed.gov/policy/rights/reg/ocr/edlite-34cfr100.html) – "No *person* in the United States shall, on the ground of race, color, or national origin be excluded from participation in, be denied the benefits of, or be otherwise subjected to discrimination under any program to which this part applies". Genetic information anti-discrimination laws are limited to employment and insurance, see [here](https://www.eeoc.gov/statutes/genetic-information-nondiscrimination-act-2008). In addition, I'm betting that your dog cannot meet the [university admission standards](https://catalog.uta.edu/academicregulations/admissions/undergraduate/) (lack of a transcript is fatal to the plan).

Comment: Bart might also have to get a waiver for the meningitis vaccine requirement.

Comment: This answer doesn't have anything to do with the question. OP isn't asking about federal anti-discrimination laws; OP is asking about UT's anti-discrimination policy. As quoted, at least, it is not on its face limited to people or to employment/insurance.

Comment: Look at the question: "In accordance with federal and state law..."

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said... no.

The University *may* disallow the application based solely on the fact that your dog is not in fact, human. If Bart were able to pass the entrance criteria for the college, they still have the ability to discriminate against dog, feline, dolphin, or other species as species is not one of the [protected classes](https://content.next.westlaw.com/5-501-5857?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)&firstPage=true) in discrimination.

Now, to the specific "clause" (not really a clause) you are pointing out, relates to things like the following:

- Disease or disorder either manifested or not in genetic testing
- Specific propensity to certain medical conditions including mental illness
- Increased risk of getting a disease, disorder, or condition in the future
- Participation in genetic testing, treatment, or analysis
- Information about a fetus held by a pregnant individual

So basically what it says is that "anything your genetics tell you, **can't be used against you** in discrimination", it does not mean that anything with gene's can be admitted because poor Bart would fail to be included in other protected classes.

Now, if in fact Bart can communicate (not necessarily talk), pass entrance criteria for the college (including obtaining a GED and passing any entrance exams like the SAT or ACT), and be financially capable of attending, the college *can admit Bart*, however they would not be discriminating a protected class if they decided not to admit him.

Answer (score -1):

NO

People think that the law allows interpretation of sentences in the way it could benefit them, but it does not.  If your dog were a Homo Erectus, it *might* apply, but everyone knows this applies to humans.

Comment: Huh? The law doesn't allow interpretations of sentences in ways that can benefit people? What interpretations are even possible that don't benefit someone? How could this language possibly benefit a 2 million-year-old fossil, but not a dog?